# Enabling Multiple Monitor Support from Terminal Services/Remote Desktop over Citrix

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, citrix

Our Remote Desktop/Terminal Services solution where I work relies on Citrix for machines not connected via the VPN. We're using Citrix Xen server (I'm pretty sure) and I'm going to try to connect to a Windows 7 Host (my work computer) and I think the RDC client runs on a Win2003 host (exposed via Citrix).

Is it possible to take advantage of Windows 7 multiple monitor support for RDC with this setup? Would I need to try getting my Citrix guys to have a different host machine for the RDC (Win2008, or Win7?)?

I'm probably going to connect using the OS X Citrix client, but I'd be willing to BootCamp/Fusion up a Windows instance to work remotely, as well. I really want to be able to use multiple monitors remotely.

It does "span" multiple montiors currently (I have a 3000x1024 desktop, for example) but I'd rather it be "true" multiple monitor instead of one giant desktop, if possible.

Comment: My head exploded reading your title. Fav'd. I really want to see if this is possible.

Comment: Thanks! My gut says it won't work like I want if I understand how Citrix works, but you never know :).

Comment: Favorited because I'm also currently dealing with multi-monitor weirdness and Citrix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what version of Citrix XenApp (formerly Presentation Server) that you are using. According to this article -- [Citrix Multi-monitor Configuration Settings and Reference](http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx115637) -- "Enhanced multi-monitor support was introduced in and requires Hotfix Rollup Pack 1 for Citrix Presentation Server 4.5 and version 10.100 of the Presentation Server for Windows Client or later."

Later in the article you'll notice that "...it is very important to calculate the amount of ICA session graphics required. This is the memory allocated to each session for its graphics data and it is set to the default of 5120 KB and limited to 8192 KB in the Access Management Console."

Comment: Jason the link you have posted is broken. I think it is missing a 7 at the end of the URL. Shouldn't it be http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX115637 ?

Comment: This is what it took - an updated version of the server and client.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my answer with the correct URL per Sim's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend a lot on the version of XenApp, and the ICA client version installed on your client.  It is possible in XenApp 4.5 SR1 and up.

Comment: I'll check with our Citrix guys and try to set something up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So if i understand well:
-User open a citrix connection
-It launch a published application, RDP Client

What you want at the end is using more than one monitor on the client side for one single published application ?

As it's the Citrix client that will drive on the remote workstation, having an RDC with multiple monitor won't help. It's encapsulated in the citrix client.

Multiple monitor support must be added on the citrix layer.

Citrix support multiple monitor for a long time:
http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX115637

Answer (score 0):

You also have to be running Windows 7 Ultimate on the machine you are RDPing into.  The other Windows 7 versions don't support the multi-monitor feature.

Comment: Citrix is not using the RDC client, so it won't help to have Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

We have a client running dual portrait mode monitors to a Win2k3 terminal server via Citrix from XP clients, but I'll have to check what the details are - I wasn't involved in setting it up in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using dual monitors in Xenapp for 4 years now since Xenapp 4.  I don't think this should be a problem.  This will work both with web interface, pnagent, receiver etc.  If you are on a very old version of Xenapp then it may not work.